# PDFsharp: Draw past edge of PdfPage

Tags: .net, pdfsharp

Is it possible to draw outside the edges of a PdfPage in PDFsharp?

Example:

```
using(XGraphics g = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(pdfPage))
{
    g.DrawRectangle(XPens.Gray, XBrushes.Gray, new XRect(-10, -10, pdfPage.Width + 20, pdfPage.Height + 20));
}
```

I am using PDFsharp to generate the contents of a book for CreateSpace, and they require a certain amount of bleed past the edge of the page for full-page images. When I save my PDFsharp PDF and upload it for validation, it shows that the drawings are not extending past the edge of the page.

Update: just have to set the BleedBox. Thanks Bally!

```
private XRect GetOversizedPageRect(PdfPage page)
{
    double bleed = XUnit.FromInch(1f / 8f);
    XRect bleedRect = new XRect(
        0 - bleed,
        0 - bleed,
        page.Width + (2 * bleed),
        page.Height + (2 * bleed)
    );
    page.BleedBox = new PdfRectangle(bleedRect);
    return bleedRect;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you have to set the BleedBox to avoid this warning.

Comment: I expect you're right about the BleedBox. It still isn't working but I'm going to continue researching and testing in this area.

Comment: Got it working...there was a math error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. PDFsharp does not clip anything you draw on a page.

Some PDF rendering tools will rely on the BleedBox to enable bleeding (drawing outside the MediaBox).

Comment: But I'm currently drawing past the edge of the page, and CreateSpace says that the drawings are not bleeding past the page edge. Are they wrong? Or is there a setting I am missing?

Comment: See the other comment. The PDF page has contents outside the media box, but a PDF processor that clips drawings to the BleedBox will not draw anything outside the MediaBox, so it may be necessary to set the BleedBox to get the desired effect.